# How discover the binding configuration to authenticate in web service

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, wsdl

I made a client to consume a web service, in Visual Studio 2010, using WSDL to auto create the proxy classes. In development environment, that is ok, is working fine, because it don't need to authenticate in this environment.

The problem i have is that the service, in test and production (the true working) environment, it have authentication. The WSDL don't describe it. Both of them use the same WSDL of development environment.

If i try to view the WSDL, using browser, in test environment, putting the "?WSDL" after the endpoint address, it don't returns the WSDL, like the development environment. It returns an authentication form, a normal html, and after inform user and password it returns the WSDL (same as development environment).

I made the app.config binding configs like this:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="WebServiceSoapAuth" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"  maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8"  useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
            <security mode="None">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
            </security>
          </binding>  
        </wsHttpBinding>
```

If i use the basicHttpBinding, that was created automatically by VS 2010 (works in dev environment), my service consumer returns "The security token could not be authenticated or authorized", as expected.

Changing to wsHttpBinding (code above), it returns "The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: " followed by the form authentication html code.

I can't figure what binding configuration i have to use.

I tested the service consumption using SoapUI, and works in both environments, and to it works using authentication, i just had to inform user, password and needed to change the "WSS-Password Type" request config to "PasswordText" (informing just user and password i have the "The security token could not be authenticated or authorized" return).

I'm sorry about my bad english, i'm not fluent, and if i made some mistake in question category or formatting it.

**EDIT:** I CAN'T VISUALIZE the wsdl file in environment with authentication. When i put address followed by ?WSDL, it gives me a form to authenticate (A form from Ensemble InterSystems software), not the wsdl.

**I tested the service consumption using SoapUI, and works in both environments, and to it works using authentication, i just had to inform user, password and needed to change the "WSS-Password Type" request config to "PasswordText" (informing just user and password i have the "The security token could not be authenticated or authorized" return).**

Why it does not work using auto generated classes, just informing the user and pass? Someone have idea?
What binding configuration is equivalent to SoapUI configuration's "WSS-Password Type" equals "PasswordText"? (i guess this is the key of why it doesn't work if i just inform user and password)

**EDIT 2**: The body of the soap message is ok. I'm having trouble making the header. It might be something like:

`<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-5">
            <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">E1XqZ2v8IDaTBzfF3j/TOA==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2012-12-21T12:24:23.380Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>`

As i told, i don't have access to the server, it is at my customer. I just know that it is made in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make manually a http webrequest, and had to create the xml manually and passed it to to request. The postData variable comes from the xml manually created.

```
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://site.customer/ens/qa/customer.bs.ws.service.cls"), HttpWebRequest)
    req.Method() = "POST"
    req.UserAgent = "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)"
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
    req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    req.KeepAlive = True
    req.Host = "site.customer"
    req.AutomaticDecompression = 3
    req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://www.tempuri.org/customer.bs.ws.service.function")
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should check that the client uses the same binding as the server. If for example your client uses wsHttpBinding but is pointing to a service which uses basicHttpBinding then it will in almost all cases go wrong.

Secondly, you set the security mode to none which means that it won't use transport or message security and I don't think that is what you want. 
If you want to use

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
```

and

```
<message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
```

then you should set security mode to TransportWithMessageCredential. This will use transport security for HTTPS and Message security for authentication. The other security modes will only use one of the clientCredentialType (transport will use transport clientCredentialType and Message will use Message clientCredentialType).

Hope this helps :).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but doing your suggestion i receive the message error before the client send anything 
"The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
Parameter name: via"

Is there a way that i can discover what is the binding configuration? How can the SoapUI make it work?

Comment: The WSDL of the service gives which binding it uses. You can just create a config for it using Svcutil to generate the client or look for yourself at the WSDL by adding ?wsdl behind the service. If you are look manually you should look for something like: `<wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IService1">`

Comment: The error can also mean that you still have your security mode on none. Set it to `<security mode="Transport">` or `<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">`

Comment: i have the following bind on the wsdl file i can see (the one after inform user and password in form returned from service, using browser):
`<binding name="WebServiceGeralSoap" type="s0:WebServiceGeralSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="Cadastrar">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.tempuri.org/thyssen.bs.ws.TotalSetor.Cadastrar" style="document"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>`

Comment: This is getting very specific. I suggest you check the web.config on the server and compare it with yours to see where it goes wrong. Or check what settings soapui uses by right clicking on the the interface and choose interface viewer.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rutix, i'll try it. But today i'll be doing another task, tomorrow i'll try it and inform here about results.

Comment: can you look at new information i provided? Can you help with this?

Comment: Please, can someone help with this problem?